# Spring data JPA entity update mechanism with database

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```
A {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  List<B> listB;
}
```

Suppose A has a list of B, if I update A using `A.setListB(anotherList)`, items in the original listB are still in the database, what should I do to automatically delete items B which are not in the new listB when I update A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JPA, you typically do not reassign list/collection variables, as this leads to errors. This is due to the JPA provider "tracking" the collections when you load an object from the database. Rather, you should do this:

```
listB.clear();
listB.addAll(otherList);
```

Combined with `orphanRemoval=true` as suggested by the other answer, it should behave the way that you wish it to.

Comment: If I clear list first, but get an error when adding item, does JPA rollback to original list?

Comment: If an exception is thrown within a transaction, it will be rolled back, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `orphanRemoval=true` on your annotation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18591766)

Comment: Sorry, for my rather inconvenient phrasing, so that my post look like a guess. I promise to improve my future answers. I did not want to critique or request clarification from the author. Using `orphanRemoval=true` part of the List annotation is a suggestion to the author and a possible solution to the problem.